# Filtering form keys/names

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, webforms

I currently have something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="foo_1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="foo_2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="bar_2"/>
```

I only need the form values where the key starts with `foo`:

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Cast<string>().Where(key => 
                                                       key.StartsWith("foo_")))
{
    //get value (123) + the ending number from the string (1 and 2 in this case)
}
```

I'm not a fan of splitting the string nor filtering on keys that starts with something. I suppose there must be a much "prettier" way of doing this? Perhaps something like

```
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="[foo][1]"/>
```

Comment: Disabled inputs are not posted, but this requires a complete iteration, either when generating the form (server side), or on before post (client side).

Comment: The inputs are not disabled, they are hidden; which are obviously posted.

Comment: Hidden != disabled.  So they should be posted.  ASP.NET does not have a object mapping system, so you will have to iterate over the form elements. C# MVC however can map elements to objects, which might be what you are looking for, however, you have to build the entire site in a MVC model to achieve this.

Comment: @Kami Ok. This is webforms as you probably have figured out. Should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Hey, I'm not saying they are not hidden. I was merely suggesting that if you set them to `disabled` the will not get posted.

Comment: @AndreiV Why would I want to do that? As you see in my example, I'm fetching them on the serverside.

Comment: I suspect ClientIDMode == Auto, ids are autogenerated, right?

Comment: @SergeyS They don't get an id, so I suppose it's off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give all the controls the same name `foo`, without a suffix.

Then, on the server side, look for `Request.Form["foo"]`. It will contain all the values, comma separated. You can then split them with `string.Split()`

If you need to keep several chunks of data (for example, the number and the related data) you can

- use an special format, for example number-dash data, like "1-firstValue", "2-secondValue". You can format it when rendering the page and parse it when getting posted values.
- use a well known serializer, for example JSON.Net. When you create the hidden fields, you set the serialized data as value. Whe you get the posted values, you unserialize them (besides, you can esaily manipulate the JSON data on client side).

If you use JSON serializer you can even keep all the data in a single hidden field, and recover it easily on server side.

You can use the well known, well documented, easy to use, [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for this. (There are versions of this for older .NET frameworks, if you're using and old version).

Comment: Well, at least it's better than my current solution :) Thanks. However, this doesn't take the ending number in to consideration, which I also need. But I'll figure something out